# split a user inputed string at a specific letter in c

Tags: c, split

I am trying to write an if else statement that looks at a user input and then splits it after index[1] if the string includes the letter b or split after index[0] if the string input doesnt include the letter b. How would I approach that? Pretty new to C so not too sure.

This is what I have so far... I think im on the right path and am trying to figure out how I would finish it off so it does what I want it to do.

```
int split_note_and_chord(char* string, char* note, char* chord)
{
  for(user input doesnt have b in it)
  {
    if(i = 0; i <index; i++)
    {
      note[i] = string[i];
    }
    note[index] = 0;
    else{ if(i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
      note[i] = strlen(string[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: int split_note_and_chord(char* string, char* note, char* chord) {
    for(user input doesnt have b in it){
        if(i = 0; i <index; i++){
            note[i] = string[i];
        }
        note[index] = 0;
    else{
        if(i = 0; i < index; i++){
            note[i] = strlen(string[2]);
        }
    }
    }
}

Comment: this is what I have so far... I think im on the right path and am trying to figure out how I would finish it off so it does what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

C string is nothing but a char array

`string.h` provides handy functions to check the string contents

you can use if condition and `strstr` and `strchr` functions for your logic

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main () {
   const char *input = "backwards";
   char *ret;

   ret = strstr(input, "b");

   if( ret != NULL ) {

   } else {

   }
}
```

The `strstr` will return `NULL` if the `b` does not exist

You can also use `strchr` if you want the second argument as single char `strchr(input, 'b');`

Comment: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/splitting-a-string-using-strtok-in-c

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach splitting your input string after the 2nd character if the input contains `'b'` or after the 1st character otherwise. Since you are dealing with either a `1` or `2`, all you need to do is determine if `'b'` is present. The easiest way to do that is with `strchr()` which will search a given string for the first occurrence of a character, returning a pointer to that character if found, or `NULL` otherwise. See [man 3 strchr](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

So you can use `strchr` to test if `'b'` is present, if the return isn't `NULL` split the string after the 2nd character, if it is `NULL`, split it after the first.

A simple implementation using a ternary to set the split-after size for input read into a buffer `buf` would be:

```
        char part2[MAXC];                       /* buffer to hold 2nd part */
        size_t split;                           /* number of chars to split */
        /* if buf contains 'b', set split at 2, otherwise set at 1 */
        split = strchr(buf, 'b') ? 2 : 1;
        strcpy (part2, buf + split);            /* copy part2 from buf */
        buf[split] = 0;                         /* nul-terminate buf at split */
```

A quick implementation allowing you to enter as many strings as you like and it will split after the 1st or 2nd character depending on the absense, or presence of `'b'` would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold line of input */

    fputs ("Enter a string to split (or [Enter] alone to exit)\n\n"
            "string: ", stdout);

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {          /* loop reading each line */
        char part2[MAXC];                       /* buffer to hold 2nd part */
        size_t split;                           /* number of chars to split */
        if (*buf == '\n')                       /* if [Enter] alone, exit */
            break;
        /* if buf contains 'b', set split at 2, otherwise set at 1 */
        split = strchr(buf, 'b') ? 2 : 1;
        strcpy (part2, buf + split);            /* copy part2 from buf */
        buf[split] = 0;                         /* nul-terminate buf at split */

        printf ("  part1: %s\n  part2: %s\nstring: ", buf, part2);
    }
}
```

(**note:** if you are unfamiliar with the *ternary* operator, it is simple `(test) ? if_true : if_false`. Above it is just shorthand for `if (strchar (buf, 'b') != NULL) split = 2; else split = 1;`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/splitb
Enter a string to split (or [Enter] alone to exit)

string: look out
  part1: l
  part2: ook out

string: look out below
  part1: lo
  part2: ok out below

string:
```

Let me know if this is what you intended. If not, I'm happy to help further. Also, if you have any questions, just let me know.

---

**Edit Based on Comment**

It is still unclear what your list of notes are in your header file, but you can simply use a string constant to contain the letters of the notes, e.g.

```
#define NOTES "abcdefg"     /* (that can be a string constant as well) */
```

(you can add upper case if needed or you can convert the input to lower -- whatever works for you)

If you simply need to find the first occurrence of one of the letters in the `NOTES` string, then `strpbrk()` will allow you to do just that returning a pointer to the first character of `NOTES` found in your `string`. (you must have some way to handle the user entering, e.g. `"the note cflat"`, which would split on the first `'e'` instead of `'c'`, but you will need to provide further specifics there)

Another consideration is how long `note` can be. If it is always 1-character, then you can simplify by just comparing against the first character in the string using `strchr (NOTES, buf[0])` (which turns the way you normally think about using `strchr()` around -- using the fist string `NOTES` and the first char read from user input.

Taking a general approach that would break `"---cflat---"` into `"---c"` and `"flat---"`, your function could be similar to:

```
int split_note_and_chord (char *string, char *note, char *chord)
{
    char *p = strpbrk (string, NOTES);  /* pointer to first of NOTES in string */

    if (p != NULL) {                    /* if found */
        strcpy (note, string);          /* copy string to note */
        note[p - string + 1] = 0;       /* nul-terminate after note */
        strcpy (chord, p + 1);          /* copy rest to chord */

        return 1;                       /* return success */
    }

    *note = 0;      /* make note and chord empty-string */
    *chord = 0;

    return 0;       /* return failure */
}
```

(**note:** if there is no char in `NOTES` found, then `note` and `chord` are made the empty-string by *nul-terminating* at the first character before returning zero to indication no-note found.)

A quick implementation similar to the first could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024           /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define NOTES "abcdefg"     /* (that can be a string constant as well) */

int split_note_and_chord (char *string, char *note, char *chord)
{
    ...
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC],     /* buffer to hold line of input */
        note[MAXC],     /* buffer for node */
        chord[MAXC];    /* buffer for chord */

    fputs ("Enter a string with node and chord (or [Enter] alone to exit)\n\n"
           "string: ", stdout);

    /* loop reading each line until [Enter] alone */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) && *buf != '\n') {
        if (split_note_and_chord (buf, note, chord))
            printf ("  note  : %s\n  chord : %s\n", note, chord);
        else
            fputs ("\nerror: note not found in string.\n\n", stderr);
        fputs ("string: ", stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** that using `fgets()` will read and include the `'\n'` resulting from the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `buf` and thus it will also be included in the remainder copied to `chord`. You can use `buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;` to trim it from `buf` -- or from `chord` by substituting `chord` for `buf` in the call using `strcspn()` as the index to nul-terminate at.)

(**also note:** you can adjust `MAXC` to fit your needs -- which is why you declare a constant in the first place -- to make it a simple change of one line at the top of your file)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your function to split various input would result in the following:

```
$ ./bin/splitb3
Enter a string with node and chord (or [Enter] alone to exit)

string: ---cflat---
  note  : ---c
  chord : flat---

string: asharp
  note  : a
  chord : sharp

string: bflat
  note  : b
  chord : flat

string: hook

error: note not found in string.

string: c
  note  : c
  chord :
```

There are many, many different way to do this and how to best approach it will depend on how you have your notes and chords defined in your header -- as well as what, if any, limitations you put on what format you require the user to enter. If you need more help, please edit your question and *Add* the contents of your header so we will know how they are declared and defined, as well as listing any constraints you want to place on what the user can enter.

Comment: Hey David thanks for the help, the more I look at my issue I think I am going about this the wrong way, so my problem is that I want the user to input a string that includes a note name and a chord name in the terminal as a single string but then I want to return the note and chord as two separate strings. I already have all my notes and chords defined in a .h folder that is why I am using int split(char* string, char* note, char* chord) it would be easier to just find the note name in the single string and split there, but how would I do it so my split function knows where to split the string

Comment: The split function would work exactly the same way. The key is you must provide adequate storage in both `note` and `chord` so that whatever you split from `string` will fit in each. When you pass `string` you can use `strbprk` to find the first of any of the characters in a given `accept` string (see `man 3 strpbrk`) and then copy and split `string` at the character pointed to y the return of `strpbrk`. If you still want to split after `str[0]` or `str[1]` it would work exactly as shown above. If stuck, drop another comment.